# Send an EC2 email with SES through the AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ses

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to send an SES email from a Linux EC2 instance through AWS CLI. I looked at some examples saying that it's better to use SMTP, saying SES would work but no details behind, or some saying it's not possible.

I have tried this:

```
aws ses send-raw-email --from-arn arn:aws:ec2:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>:instance/<instance-id> --destinations <list>
```

but I didn't get anything.

Comment: It is absolutely possible. There is no reason at all why the AWS CLI tool wouldn't work on an EC2 instance the same as it would work anywhere else. If you aren't receiving an error when you run that `aws ses` command, then the CLI command probably works, but you most likely haven't configured your SES environment correctly yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't get anything"? Did you at least receive an error message?

Comment: Might help: [aws-cli: awscli/examples/ses/send-raw-email.rst | Fossies](https://fossies.org/linux/aws-cli/awscli/examples/ses/send-raw-email.rst)

Answer (score 0):

As per the help page of send-raw-email `aws ses send-raw-email help`, parameter `--from-arn` is the resource name of the **verified identity** you configure in SES.

> *This parameter is used only for sending authorization. It is the ARN of  the  identity  that is associated with the sending authorization
> policy that permits you to specify a particular  "From"  address  in
> the header of the raw email.*

More importantly it is **not** the ARN of the EC2 instance from which you are invoking the CLI.

Consider the examples below:

1. Without parameter `--from-arn`, instead using `--source`

```
% aws ses send-raw-email --source saini001@gmail.com --destinations saini001@gmail.com --raw-message file://email.json --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out
{
    "MessageId": "0100017fc8dc8fbd-34f5bf83-ac26-4bd5-aa69-7358d96d925a-000000"
}
```

2. Using `--from-arn`

```
% aws ses send-raw-email --from-arn arn:aws:ses:us-region-x:xxxxx:identity/saini001@gmail.com --destinations saini001@gmail.com --raw-message file://email.json --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out
{
    "MessageId": "0100017fc8df4fd7-3c21d871-3883-4d4c-8c82-17cbfd479e5f-000000"
}
```

In both cases, SES sent email to the specified destination.